# why is hovering over emoji logs console error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, emoji, web-frontend

```
  const all_emoji = [
    ``,
    ``,
    ``,
  ];
```

```
      <div
        className="chat-box-emoji-picker"
        ref={scroll_content_ref}
        onScroll={compute_scroller}
      >
        {all_emoji.map((emoji) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={emoji}
              className="chat-box-emoji-picker-item"
              onClick={() => {
                on_select(emoji);
              }}
            >
              {emoji}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

The above errors logs out in the console when I hover over the emojis with my mouse. Don't know why

Comment: Maybe unrelated but some emojis will break json parse as well.

Comment: @GetSet [citation needed]

Comment: @deceze No citation, just personal experience. It was a project where I was using the json parse/stringify method to deep clone simple objects. The solution was to encode the emojis in hexadecimal before doing the parse/stringify bit.

Comment: @GetSet A concrete example would be necessary here. As is, this is just [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt). Mind you, there may be something there, just as is, it's an unsubstantiated claim.